# Python2: multiprocessing using a Pool of workers with multiple arguments

Tags: python, threadpool, python-2.x, python-multiprocessing

I want to try parallel computing in python-2.x using `multiprocessing.Pool`.

I came up with the following simple code.
Unfortunately, I was not able to produce **any** error message.

Can someone point me into the right direction of what might be wrong with my code?

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
import timeit

def fun(i,j):
    return i+j

num=2

num_cores = mp.cpu_count()
p = mp.Pool(num_cores)

results = np.array([])
tasks = np.array([(i, j) for i in range(0,num) for j in range(0, num)])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    results = np.array(p.map(fun,tasks))
    print results
```

Comment: Is the fact, that the `return` in your `fun` function in not indented intentional? Or did that happend while formatting your question for StackOverflow?

Comment: It's just the problem in formatting.

Comment: What is the expected output of your program @L.Chau? And for anyone interested in what the actual error is: `TypeError: fun() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`

Answer (score 0):

The main problem you have here is that the tuples you want to pass as arguments to the workers are wrapped in a `numpy.ndarray` and thus it is just **one argument** as the `numpy.ndarray` **does not** get unfolded.

---

This should work for you:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
import timeit

def fun(ij):
    s = sum(ij)
    print('{0} + {1} = {2}'.format(ij[0], ij[1], s))
    return s

num=2

num_cores = mp.cpu_count()
p = mp.Pool(num_cores)

results = np.array([])
tasks = np.array([(i, j) for i in range(0,num) for j in range(0, num)])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    results = np.array(p.map(fun,tasks))
    print(results)
```

The output of this script is:

```
0 + 0 = 0
0 + 1 = 1
1 + 0 = 1
1 + 1 = 2
[0 1 1 2]
```

---

I added the `from __future__ import print_function` statement, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38270409/2402281) what it is good for. And [here is the according PEP 3105 -- Make print a function](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105/).

---

Final remarks: A more throughout solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5442981/2402281) from user senderle.